# Рекурсия, как оптимизировать код?

Tags: c#, xml, wpf

Здравствуйте.

Написал код записи в xml файлы веток дерева. Но если значений в дереве много, то при нажатии на кнопку программа подвисает, как это можно исправить с помощью рекурсии или как-то по другому?

Привожу часть кода

```
 foreach(TreeViewItem zcv in tSystemCatalog.Items) {
     foreach(TreeViewItem xzvv in zcv.Items) {

         XmlTextWriter textWriter = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\" + xzvv.Tag.ToString() + ".xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);

         textWriter.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
         textWriter.WriteStartDocument();
         textWriter.WriteStartElement("Root");
         textWriter.WriteStartElement("Section");
         textWriter.WriteString(xzvv.Header.ToString());
         textWriter.WriteEndElement();
         textWriter.WriteStartElement("LinkParent");
         textWriter.WriteAttributeString("name", xzvv.Tag.ToString());
         textWriter.WriteEndElement();

         if (xzvv.HasItems == true) {
             foreach(TreeViewItem xvv in xzvv.Items) {
                 foreach(TreeViewItem xvv2 in xvv.Items) {

                     textWriter.WriteStartElement("Subsections");
                     textWriter.WriteStartElement("Subsection");
                     textWriter.WriteString(xvv2.Header.ToString());
                     textWriter.WriteEndElement();
                     textWriter.WriteEndElement();
                     textWriter2.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                     textWriter2.WriteStartDocument();
                     textWriter2.WriteStartElement("Root");
                     textWriter2.WriteStartElement("Section");
                     textWriter2.WriteString(xvv2.Header.ToString());
                     textWriter2.WriteEndElement();
                     textWriter2.WriteStartElement("LinkParent");
                     textWriter2.WriteAttributeString("name", xvv2.Tag.ToString());
                     textWriter2.WriteEndElement();

                     if (xvv2.HasItems == true) {
                         foreach(TreeViewItem xvv3 in xvv2.Items) {
                             foreach(TreeViewItem xvv4 in xvv3.Items) {

                                 textWriter2.WriteStartElement("Subsections");
                                 textWriter2.WriteStartElement("Subsection");
                                 textWriter2.WriteString(xvv4.Header.ToString());
                                 textWriter2.WriteEndElement();
                                 textWriter2.WriteEndElement();
                                 XmlTextWriter textWriter3 = new XmlTextWriter("D:\\" + xvv4.Tag.ToString().Trim() + ".xml", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
                                 textWriter3.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
                                 textWriter3.WriteStartDocument();
                                 textWriter3.WriteStartElement("Root");
                                 textWriter3.WriteStartElement("Section");
                                 textWriter3.WriteString(xvv4.Header.ToString());
                                 textWriter3.WriteEndElement();
                                 textWriter3.WriteStartElement("LinkParent");
                                 textWriter3.WriteAttributeString("name", xvv4.Tag.ToString().Trim());
                                 textWriter3.WriteEndElement();
                             }
                         }

                         if (xvv4.HasItems == true) {
                             textWriter3.WriteEndElement();
                             textWriter3.WriteEndDocument();
                             textWriter3.Close();
                         } else if (xvv4.HasItems == false) {
                             textWriter3.WriteEndElement();
                             textWriter3.WriteEndDocument();
                             textWriter3.Close();
                         }
                     }
                 }

                 textWriter2.WriteEndElement();
                 textWriter2.WriteEndDocument();
                 textWriter2.Close();
             } else if (xvv2.HasItems == false) {
                 textWriter2.WriteEndElement();
                 textWriter2.WriteEndDocument();
                 textWriter2.Close();
             }
         }
     }

     textWriter.WriteEndElement();
     textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
     textWriter.Close();
 } else if (xzvv.HasItems == false) {
     textWriter.WriteEndElement();
     textWriter.WriteEndDocument();
     textWriter.Close();
 }
```

Comment: рекурсия может помочь упросить алгоритм, но не добавить скорости.
Рекомендую подумать над кодом вида

    if (xvv2.HasItems == true)

это не совсем красивый код (нужно просто писать `if (xvv2.HasItems)`

Comment: этот код мало похож на тот что используется в реальных приложениях, но рекурсию можно добавить. он как минимум станет намного читабельнее и понятнее

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выглядит так, что тормоза связаны с тем, что у вас в самом глубоком вложенном цикле открываются файлы. Открытие файла - достаточно дорогая операция с точки зрения ресурсов. Если элементов в исходном дереве много, то и файлов будет много - функция будет работать не быстро.

Рекомендации:

1. Подумать, а надо ли много файлов.
2. Сделать сохранение отдельных файлов асинхронным. Это может помочь на быстрых дисках, поддерживающих параллельную запись.

P.S. непонятно кто такой textWriter2 - я не нашел его инициализации

Comment: Ну да это понятно. А что вы имеете в виду под открытием файла в данном случае вроде в коде нет функции Load и подобных. Мне нужно не открывать, а записать, файлов ещё нет на диске. Может и не надо много файлов точные требования на это не устанавливались, проверил работу на 4-5 работает нормально, когда уже 10, то проявляются тормоза. textWriter2 это уже другой поток, другой файл textWriter2 проинициализирован как и все остальные просто видимо в коде забыл привести.  И как его сделать асинхронным?

Comment: Когда вы пишете в файл - вы тем самым его открываете. В вашем случае это проиходит неявно, через создание XmlTextWriter.
Асинхронным можно сделать по-разному. Почитайте про использование Task (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.task.aspx)